# how to supply row and column name from two different files to a dataframe through R

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to create a data frame by supplying row and column name from two different files.

```
File for rows:-
sample1_44849
sample2_56479
sample3_98764
sample4_54321
and so on ...


File for columns:-
e000456.c1
e000567.c1
e003456.c1
e000786.c1
and similarly 22000 more ....
```

this data frame will contain value 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to first create a `matrix` with `dimnames` corresponding to the names from the files and then convert it to a `data.frame`.

```
r.names <- read.table(text = "sample1_44849
sample2_56479
sample3_98764
sample4_54321")

c.names <- read.table(text = "e000456.c1
e000567.c1
e003456.c1
e000786.c1")

res <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(r.names), ncol = nrow(c.names),
    dimnames = list(unlist(r.names), unlist(c.names)))

res <- data.frame(res)
```

This code solves the original question. The comment at the end is a different matter.